# Create an arbitrary number of DigitalOcean droplets with Ansible

Tags: automation, ansible, digital-ocean

I want to create an arbitrary number of droplets when I call a playbook with ansible.
For example:
I need to create 10 droplets running some python code.

```
$ ansible-playbook install_pyapp_commission_new.yml --extra-vars "number_of_droplets_to_create=10"
```

I tried using `with_sequence: count = X` but you can't apply it to roles, or inside tasks (as far as I know). My playbook looks something like this:

```
- name: Digital Ocean Provisioning
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local
  roles:
    - { role: do_provision, do_droplet_number: "{{ number_of_droplets_to_create | default(01) }}" }

- name: Setting up application
  gather_facts: true
  user: root
  hosts: do_instances
  roles:
    - { role: application, wait_time: 60 }
```

So I pass the input number of droplets to `do_provision` as `do_droplet_number` because atm I create one per run (this way I can run 10 in parallel from bash, each with a different number, thus achieving my goal, but it's a dirty solution).

I wanted to do something like this:

```
- name: Digital Ocean Provisioning
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local
  roles:
    - { role: do_provision, do_droplet_number: "{{ item }}" }
  with_sequence: count={{ number_of_droplets_to_create }}
```

But this is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

This should work using loop instead of with_sequence.

It shifts the loop into the role, because playbooks can't include the 'when'. 
The 'when' is needed to prevent a droplet from being created when do_droplet_number is 0.

**playbook**

```
- name: list hosts
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false  

  vars:
    thiscount: "{{ mycount | default('0') }}"

  roles:
    - { role: do-provision, do_droplet_number: "{{ thiscount }}" }
```

**roles/do-provision/task/main.yml**

```
- name: display number
  debug:
    msg: "mycount {{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ range(0, do_droplet_number|int) |list }}"
  when: thiscount > 0
```